# Cannot read property 'after' of undefined in implementing react-relay

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, relay, react-router-relay

In my nodejs application

here is my schema.js file

```
import {
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLString,
} from 'graphql';

import {
  connectionArgs,
  connectionDefinitions,
  connectionFromArray,
  connectionFromPromisedArray,
  cursorForObjectInConnection,
  fromGlobalId,
  globalIdField,
  mutationWithClientMutationId,
  nodeDefinitions,
  toGlobalId,
} from 'graphql-relay';

import {
  User,
  getUser,
  getPosts,
  createpost,
} from '../data/database.js';

var { nodeInterface, nodeField } = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    var { type, id } = fromGlobalId(globalId);
    if (type === 'User') {
      return getUser(id);
    }else if (type === 'Post') {
      return getPosts(id);
    }
    return null;
  },
  (obj) => {
    if (obj instanceof User) {
      return userType;
    }else if (obj instanceof Post) {
      return postType;
    }
    return null;
  }
);

var userProfileImageType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'ProfileImage',
  fields: {
    full: {
      type: GraphQLString
    }
  }
});

var userLocalAccountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Local',
  fields: {
    email: {
      type: GraphQLString
    }
  }
});

var userFacebookAccountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Facebook',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    displayName: {
      type: GraphQLString
    }
  }
});

var userGoogleAccountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Google',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    displayName: {
      type: GraphQLString
    }
  }
});

var postType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Post',
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField('Post'),
    title: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    userId: globalIdField('User'),
    content: {
      type: GraphQLString
    }
  },
  interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});

/**
 * Define your own connection types here
 */

const {
  connectionType: postConnection,
  edgeType: postEdge,
} = connectionDefinitions({name: 'Post', nodeType: postType});

let createPostMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
    name: 'CreatePost',

    inputFields: {
      title: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
      content: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
      userId: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    },

    outputFields: {
      postEdge: {
        type: postConnection,
        resolve: (obj) => ({ node: obj, cursor: obj.insertedId })
      },
    },

    mutateAndGetPayload: ({title, content,userId}) => {
      console.log({title, content,userId})
      return createpost({title, content,userId})
    }
  });

var userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField('User'),
    fullName: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: "Users' Full Name"
    },
    isPremium: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
      description: "Does the user have premium subscription?"
    },
    currentPostCount: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      description: "User's current total post"
    },
    images: {
      type: userProfileImageType,
      description: "User's profile image links"
    },
    local: {
      type: userLocalAccountType,
      description: "User's local account info"
    },
    facebook: {
      type: userFacebookAccountType,
      description: "User's Facebook account info"
    },
    google: {
      type: userGoogleAccountType,
      description: "User's Google Plus account info"
    },
    posts: {
      type: postConnection,
      args: {
        ...connectionArgs,
        query: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve: (rootValue) => {
        return connectionFromPromisedArray(getPosts(rootValue))
      }
    },
  },
  interfaces: [nodeInterface]
});

var Root = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Root',
  fields: () => ({
    user: {
      type: userType,
      resolve: (rootValue, _) => {
        return getUser(rootValue)
      }
    },
  })
})

export var schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: Root,
  mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: () => ({
      createPost: createPostMutation
    })
  })
});
```

and below is my database.js

```
import User from './models/userModel'
import Post from './models/postModel'

export { User }
export { Post }

export function getUser(user) {
  let validUser = false
  if (user.local || user.facebook || user.google) {
    validUser = true
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (validUser) {
      let localEmail = user.local.email || ""
      let googleID = user.google.id || ""
      let facebookID = user.facebook.id || ""
      User.findOne({
        $or: [
          { "local.email": localEmail },
          { "facebook.id": facebookID },
          { "google.id": googleID }
        ]
      }, function(err, existingUser) {
        if (err || !existingUser) {
          resolve({})
        } else {
          resolve(existingUser)
        }
      });
    } else {
      resolve({})
    }
  })
}

export function getPosts(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     Post.find({}).exec({}, function(err, posts) {
        resolve(posts)
      });

  })
}

export function createpost({title, content,userId}){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const blogPostModel = new Post({title, content,userId});
      const newBlogPost = blogPostModel.save();
      if (!newBlogPost) {
        throw new Error('Error adding new blog post');
      }
       resolve({})
  })
}
```

I am getting user by

```
Relay.QL `query { user}`
```

I want to fetch all posts along with user

```
Relay.QL 'query{
  user {
    id,
    posts(first: 3) {
      edges {
        node {
          id,
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

but i am getting below error in terminal

```
    Failed to execute query `UserQueries` for the following reasons:

1. Cannot read property 'after' of undefined
   le {id,displayName},_posts3KBCho:posts(first:3) {edges {node
```

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update #1:**

The problem is in the implementation of `posts` field in `userType` definition.

```
posts: {
  type: postConnection,
  args: {
    ...connectionArgs,
    query: { type: GraphQLString }
  },
  resolve: (rootValue) => {
    return connectionFromPromisedArray(getPosts(rootValue))
  }
},
```

While destructuring `args`,  the [Rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `connectionArgs` should come in the end. `query` should come first. Because of the wrong use of rest parameters, `connectionArgs` is found `undefined`.

By the way, you don't pass `query` for posts. If you don't provide `query` argument, you should just use `args: {...connectionArgs},`.

---

Looks like you've used Mongoose library. If that's the case, one obvious problem is in the implementation of `getPosts` function. `exec` itself [returns a promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html). So, it doesn't need to be wrapped in a Promise. Replace this

```
export function getPosts(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     Post.find({}).exec({}, function(err, posts) {
        resolve(posts)
      });

  })
}
```

with this

```
export function getPosts(user) {
    return Post.find({user_id: user._id}).exec();
}
```

Please let me know if you face further problems after fixing this.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I tried that already also I console log getPosts() and I am getting posts list their. still same error is coming . 1. Cannot read property 'after' of undefined –
   flag
 
or sometimes getting error.... Cannot return null for non-nullable field PostConnection.pageInfo. le,content},cursor},pageInfo {hasNextPage,hasPreviousPage}}}

Comment: You didn't import `Post` in your `schema.js` file. What happens after you import `Post`?

Comment: It doesn't makes any difference as getposts is importing from database.js and POST is imported .

Comment: @ajooba I identified a problem in your implementation of `posts` field in `userType`. Please see my update. It should solve the issue.

Comment: @akshay For OP's immediate problem, it does not matter. But while doing [`node` root call](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33411416/2821632), `obj instanceof Post` in node definitions will cause problem. `Post` type is not imported.

Answer (score 2):

Made the same mistake today and it took me little bit to find right solution. I looked at your question with same issue, but didn't resolved my problem. After some time I've noticed I'm missing `args` in my `connectionFromPromisedArray` call. So to fix your issue try changing this:

```
posts: {
      type: postConnection,
      args: {
        ...connectionArgs,
        query: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve: (rootValue, args) => { // <== here is added args attribute
        return connectionFromPromisedArray(getPosts(rootValue), args) // <== here is added args attribute
      }
    },
```