# Unable to fetch list in react relay

Tags: node.js, reactjs, relay

I am following schema same as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540767/cannot-read-property-after-of-undefined-in-implementing-react-relay)

I want to fetch all users so I updated my schema like this

```
var Root = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Root',
  fields: () => ({
    user: {
      type: userType,
      resolve: (rootValue, _) => {
        return getUser(rootValue)
      }
    },
    post: {
      type: postType,
      args: {
         ...connectionArgs,
          postID: {type: GraphQLString}
        },
      resolve: (rootValue, args) => {
       return getPost(args.postID).then(function(data){
        return data[0];
       }).then(null,function(err){
        return err;
       });
      }
    },

    users:{
      type: new GraphQLList(userType),
      resolve: (root) =>getUsers(),
    },
  })
});
```

And in database.js

```
export function getUsers(params) {
  console.log("getUsers",params)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      User.find({}).exec({}, function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
          resolve({})
        } else {
          resolve(users)
        }
      });
  })
}
```

I am getting results in /graphql as

```
{
  users {
    id,
    fullName
  } 
}
```

and results as

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "VXNlcjo1Nzk4NWQxNmIwYWYxYWY2MTc3MGJlNTA=",
        "fullName": "Akshay"
      },
      {
        "id": "VXNlcjo1Nzk4YTRkNTBjMWJlZTg1MzFmN2IzMzI=",
        "fullName": "jitendra"
      },
      {
        "id": "VXNlcjo1NzliNjcyMmRlNjRlZTI2MTFkMWEyMTk=",
        "fullName": "akshay1"
      },
      {
        "id": "VXNlcjo1NzliNjgwMDc4YTYwMTZjMTM0ZmMxZWM=",
        "fullName": "Akshay2"
      },
      {
        "id": "VXNlcjo1NzlmMTNkYjMzNTNkODQ0MmJjOWQzZDU=",
        "fullName": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but If I try to fetch this in view as

```
export default Relay.createContainer(UserList, {
  fragments: {
    userslist: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User @relay(plural: true) {
            fullName,
            local{
              email
            },
            images{
              full
            },
            currentPostCount,
            isPremium,
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

I am getting error `Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.`

Please tell me what I am missing .
I tried a lot with and without @relay(plural: true).
Also tried to update schema with arguments as

```
    users:{
      type: new GraphQLList(userType),
      args: {
        names: {
          type: GraphQLString,
        },
        ...connectionArgs,
      },
      resolve: (root, {names}) =>connectionFromArray(getUsers(names)),
    },
```

but I got error `Cannot read property 'after' of undefined in implementing react-relay`
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where do you define `userslist`?

Comment: I defined user list in routes.js

Comment: Relay.ql'{  users}

Comment: As the error suggested, did you try out non minified dev environment and get a detailed error message?

Comment: I got message Invariant Violation: RelayOSSNodeInterface: Expected payload for root field `users` to be a single non-array result, instead received an array with 5 results

Comment: Which version of Relay are you using? List-type root field in query is now supported.

Comment: here are versions list of all relays packages , "react-relay": "0.8.1", "graphql-relay": "0.4.1", "isomorphic-relay-router": "0.8.0-beta.0", "isomorphic-relay": "0.7.0-beta.0", "relay-local-schema": "0.5.0", "babel-relay-plugin": "0.8.1",

Comment: It may be a good idea to look at star-wars example of relay. It also has a query where a [root query field is a list](https://github.com/relayjs/relay-examples/blob/3a134b03fa9b741754f0b2e6ad15b5da79151846/star-wars/data/schema.js#L234).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Relay currently only supports three types of root fields (see [facebook/relay#112](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/112)):

- Root field without arguments, returning a single node:

  - e.g. `{ user { id } }` returning `{"id": "123"}`
- Root field with one argument, returning a single node:

  - e.g. `{ post(id: "456") { id } }` returning `{"id": "456"}`
- Root field with one array argument returning an array of nodes with the same size as the argument array (also known as "a plural identifying root field"):

  - e.g. `{ users(ids: ["123", "321"]) { id } }` returning `[{"id": "123"}, {"id": "321"}]`

A workaround is to create a root field (often called `viewer`) returning a node that has those fields. When nested inside the `Viewer` (or any other node), fields are allowed to have any return type, including a list or connection. When you've wrapped the fields in this object in your GraphQL server, you can query them like this:

```
{
  viewer {
    users {
      id,
      fullName,
    }
  }
}
```

The `Viewer` type is a node type, and since there will just be one instance of it, its `id` should be a constant. You can use the `globalIdField` helper to define the `id` field, and add any other fields you want to query with Relay:

```
const viewerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Viewer',
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField('Viewer', () => 'VIEWER_ID'),
    users:{
      type: new GraphQLList(userType),
      resolve: (viewer) => getUsers(),
    },
  },
});
```

On the client you'll need to change the root query in your route to `{ viewer }` and define the fragment on `Viewer`:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(UserList, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        users {
          fullName,
          local {
            email,
          },
          images {
            full,
          },
          currentPostCount,
          isPremium,
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Comment: How should viewer looks like in my schema  ?

Comment: @akshay I've now added an example `Viewer` type definition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks it woks like charm..:-)